# How to match a pattern with arbitrary characters in between?

Tags: python, regex

How to write a regexp pattern in python to match all strings containing `abc123`, like

```
a.b.c.1.2.3
a.b.c_1-2.3
a...bc12..3
a.bc1_23
ABC.123_
```

That is, where any number of arbitrary characters are being inserted in between `abc123`.

UPDATE:

I've tried things like:

```
p = ['a(.*)b(.*)c(.*)1(.*)2(.*)3(.*)']


p = ['[a](.*)[b](.*)[c](.*)[1](.*)[2](.*)[3](.*)']
```

but they did not work.

Comment: What was your effort so far?

Comment: @Jan I've added some of my efforts.

Comment: is a.b.c.a.1.2.3 a match ?

Comment: @KiraCrafter yes it is.

Comment: Use the better regex implementation from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex - then you could come up with sth. like `^([ABCabc123._-]*)(?1)$` - a recursive solution. However, it depends on what you're trying to achieve with the matches. See [a demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wB1qJ7/2)

Comment: @Jan,  I guess my main problem is how to insert `any number of characters, any number of times` between `abc123`. It should be doable in vanilla `re`. Isn't it?

Comment: @ultrax: Well, it is, just make the star quantifier lazy - https://regex101.com/r/wB1qJ7/4

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/wY5zZ2/1) what you wish to do ? Test it and let me know.

Comment: @Jan That seems to work. Please answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in the comments, a possible solution would be to make the quantifier lazy:

```
a(.*?)b(.*?)c(.*?)1(.*?)2(.*?)3(.*?)
```